# Can you paralyze dragons?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have the master archery perk that lets you paralyze targets and a paralysis bow. Is it possible for me to paralyze a dragon? In the time I've played I've not seen it and was just curious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The master archery perk (Bullseye), paralysis poisons and paralysis enchantments do not affect dragons.

Comment: All three tested with my current character against several Ancient and Elder dragons. While I don't believe dragons can be paralysed at all, there is a chance that low-level dragons are vulnerable to effects that high-level dragons are immune to. If anyone notices this, please let me know.

Comment: No, all dragons are immune to paralysis.  ALL of them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is true, but bashing the [Windshear](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Windshear) might paralyze a dragon due to its unique enchantments.

Comment: Hi Daniel Gernhard, welcome to the site! You may want to take the [tour].

Answer (score -5):

You can paralyze dragons. I'm not sure about the enchantment, but you can use the paralyze poison on them and they will stop moving.

Comment: This is just false

Comment: I've tried it before, and it worked. Maybe it was just a glitch, but it stopped moving for a good five seconds.